# Generating Predictive Models for Multiple Time Series

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, python

I have a dataset of historical film streaming data for the last few years. Each record is the Title, Genre, Rotten Tomatoes Score, Week of Streaming Data and then Raw Streaming. I am trying to find the best way to make either one, or multiple models that can forecast growth or decay. I want this model or equation to be applicable to a new movie title given the required data.

Sorry if this is too vague or poorly worded. Im not very well versed in time series data science problems sets.

Comment: This post is hidden. You deleted this post just now.
Welcome to Cross Validated. There's no question in your post. What have you tried and what is your question?